# BreakOut Detection Python/R Pkg Installation on Mac

Tags: python, macos, breakout

I have been trying to install the BreakOut Detetction pkg (by Roland Hochmuth) in a MacOS Mojave environment.

Following is the pkg I am talking about, https://github.com/roland-hochmuth/BreakoutDetection

I was able to get swig on my machine by using homebrew.

The pkg details 3 steps to install:

```
swig -python -c++ breakout_detection.i 
python setup.py build_ext -I../src build 
sudo python setup.py build_ext -I../src install
```

I got the error with the first step and shows "Unable to find file 'breakout_detection.i'."

Then I try to swig with a detailed file paths, it somehow works with the first step.
However, the second step gives a lot of compilation errors and warnings.
One of the errors shows "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1".

I was wondering if anyone has tried compiling this pkg.
I really want to know how this guy successfully compiled the pkg. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fcsyL5TwIvE)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to simply solve this issue by putting codes in the breakout detection folder where "breakout_detection.py" is.

Then you can simply "**import breakout_detection**" library and use it.